# Pull data from ServiceNow API into Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, servicenow, data-extraction, servicenow-rest-api

I need some reference to pull the data from Service Now API End Point to Snowflake Cloud Datawarehouse!

All that I am looking for a step by step guide to Extract data from Servicenow API end point (Based on authorized API ID and Password) into Snowflake Database tables.

I am new into this and Please Help

I am looking to use the built in features of Snowflake (like connectors or pipe or something else) with which I can achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Given that recommending tools is not permitted on this platform, you’ll need to provide a lot more information and the basics of a solution before anyone can help you. For example, what tool/solution are you planning to use to connect to the API.

Comment: Well I was actually looking for Built-In options with-in Snowflake and some code examples for me to try it out!

Comment: Snowflake has no etl capabilities that allow connections to other systems

Comment: Perhaps you can explore doing the following:
1. ServiceNow: "You can schedule an export to regularly push data from an export set to a remote destination."  
https://docs.servicenow.com/en-US/bundle/sandiego-platform-administration/page/administer/export-sets/task/t_ScheduleAnExport.html

2. Snowflake: COPY INTO <table> from external location.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

3. Snowflake: Create a TASK to do period COPY INTO.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html

Comment: Note that SaaS connectivity for ServiceNow was announced at Snowflake summit, and is currently in private preview.  Regardless what you may decide to do tactically here, you should keep an eye on this emerging option: https://www.snowflake.com/blog/introducing-new-snowflake-capabilities/